# why won't jetty 6.1.x run with java 1.4.2?

Tags: java, jetty, java1.4

Dcoumentation everywhere I can find suggests that jetty 6.1.x should still run with java 1.4.2.

Yet, if I download a jetty binary, and "java -jar start.jar", I get variations of:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (org/mortbay/xml/XmlConfiguration) bad major version at offset=6"

I've tried it with jetty 6.1.26 downloaded from dist.codehouse.org/jetty. I've tried with with the 'hightide' jetty release 6.1H.24 and hightide-6.1H.8.

My java is:

$ java -version
java version "1.4.2"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 2.3)
IBM J9 VM (build 2.3, J2RE 1.4.2 IBM J9 2.3 Linux amd64-64 j9vmxa64142ifx-20100113 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20100112_51454_LHdSMr
JIT  - 20090210_1447ifx1_r8
GC   - 200902_24)

I know this is anchient java here, but I've got some ancient code to run on it.  Everywhere SAYS jetty 6.1 should run on java 1.4.  I even find ancient blog posts saying they did run jetty 1.6 with java 1.4.

So what's up?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

jetty 6.1.26 in particular, and all jetty 6.1.x in general, DO run on Java 1.4, and the .jars distributed on the official site ARE compiled to work with java 1.4.

So why wasn't it working for me?

Some of the sample webapps distributed with jetty do NOT work under 1.4, they are not compiled for 1.4.  I don't know if this a packaging accident or what.

But if I delete all the sample apps, by deleting everything in ./webapps and ./contexts, then the stock distro binary jetty 6.1.26 release starts up fine under 1.4, and works fine when I install my own webapps.

Answer (score 3):

As I see on http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/what+JVMs+are+supported the latest Jetty, that runs on JDK 1.4 is 6.1.5. So, you need to get old version of jetty.

Other way is to compile jetty from source by yourself. Tutorial how to do it is on [Jetty wiki](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Building+from+Source)

Comment: Its almost certainly the case the jrochkind needs to compile from source given the UnsupportedClassVersionError.

Comment: Yes, it is clear, that jetty he uses is compiled against newer jdk. But according to the information on the jetty wiki he can take older version of jetty, say 6.1.5 and try with it. Or compile jetty by himself, as I already said.

Comment: I think maybe that page was written when 6.1.5 was the latest 6.1. Because the main download page:  http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Downloading+Jetty says "Jetty-6.1 1.4-1.6" But maybe it's wrong?  I guess maybe my experience is evidence that it's wrong, but I feel suspicious, why would the main jetty download page say that and nobody would have noticed it's wrong yet?  I'm just a bit bewildered by lack of good documentation/conflicting documentation here.

Comment: and actually yeah, even that page you cite says "jetty-6 targets Java 1.4 or above".  Then says "Some (older) specific reports of success are", before saying 1.4.2 with jetty 6.1.5.  So that's just saying someone (a long time ago) specifically verified 6.1.5 with 1.4.2 --- but still saying jetty 6.1 in general should work with java 1.4 in general. But I guess it could be wrong -- is Jetty known for having bad documentation or something?

Comment: Exception you mentioned (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (org/mortbay/xml/XmlConfiguration) bad major version at offset=6) definitely says, that jetty is compiled against later version of JDK. So, it may be error in documentation.